# Removing fragments from the backstack in a viewpager & refreshing previously viewed fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I 'm using a viewpager as a questionnaire. The user inputs their answers in the first 8 fragments, then their answers are displayed in the 10th fragment (OverviewFragment).  It's all working great. The issue I have a question about is when the user returns to a past fragment, ie: Fragment 4 and changes an answer, if they return to the 10th fragment it doesn't update.  I'm sure this is a lifecycle/backstack issue but unsure how to kick fragments off the backstack in a viewpager.  Or maybe just a way to ensure that fragment is constantly refreshed?

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private  int fragmentCount = 11;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return DemoFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return PreliminaryQuesFragment.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return QuestionOneFragment.newInstance();
            case 3:
                return QuestionTwoFragment.newInstance();
            case 4:
                return QuestionThreeFragment.newInstance();
            case 5:
                return QuestionFourFragment.newInstance();
            case 6:
                return QuestionFiveFragment.newInstance();
            case 7:
                return QuestionSixFragment.newInstance();
            case 8:
                return StatementFragment.newInstance();
            case 9:
                return OverviewFragment.newInstance(user.getTitle(), prelimAnswer, qOne, qTwo,
                        qThree, qFour, qFive);
            case 10:
                return GoodbyeFragment.newInstance(position);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentCount;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely an issue with how your Fragment's state is being restored when a Fragment that has been previously created is navigated back to -- is your FragmentStatePagerAdapter really creating a NEW fragment instance, or reusing an old one it's already been created, and using it's previous Bundle args?

I've run into a similar issue when creating Fragment's and passing a full Parcelable object as the UI Model to use when populating the Fragment's UI.  Once the Fragment was navigated back to, the original Parcelable was used when recreating the Fragment's View (so, the old, original object from the Bundle args I set on the Fragment on it's initial creation).  To get around this issue, I passed an ID reference to each Fragment in it's Bundle args instead (so, just some integer or something), that mapped to the present, in memory copy of the model Object I was trying to display in the UI.

So, even though my Fragment was recreated with the same bundle args, I would use SomeInMemoryHelperObjectContainingMyMap.get(ID) to get the most recent version of that object to populate the UI.